# Hello i am trying to display json data from url into listview. Nothing is displayed though

Tags: java, android, json

Url

private static String JSON_URL ="https://run.mocky.io/v3/aff3f637-d04f-45c0-b002-09be1a143784";

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> friendsList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    friendsList= new ArrayList<>();
    lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    GetData getData= new GetData();
    getData.execute();

}
```

Getting the data

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String current = "";

        try {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = isr.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    current += (char) data;
                    data = isr.read();
                }
                return current;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          return current;
    }
```

Displaying the data

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Friends"); //name of array

            for(int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                namey=jsonObject.getString("name");
                age= jsonObject1.getString("age");


                //Hashmap

                HashMap<String, String> friends = new HashMap<>();

                friends.put("name",namey);
                friends.put("age", age);

                friendsList.add(friends);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Displaying the results
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this,
                friendsList,
                R.layout.row_layout,
                new String[]{"name","age"},
                new int[]{R.id.textView, R.id.textView2});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

}

It doesnt display anything and i believe it has something to do with the url, but i am not quite sure so please help and thank you in advance

Comment: `String s` Have you checked the value of variable s? Toast() it to see. Log it to know. Is it empty() ? You are not checking for empty(). It will be empty if you catched an exception in doInbackground();

Comment: Your url in a browser: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 26 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: `catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
` The least you could do is to display a Toast() there to inform the user. Did you look in the logcat if there was a catch?

Comment: Hi Atanas - Take care in the formatting when posting please. Also, keep your title to the point. I tried to edit to fix the code formatting, but am unable as it is warning the question is nearly all code. It is best to do basic checks as suggested in the comments before posting. Also, you can say in your post what you have tried to do already to troubleshoot :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your mocky JSON from https://run.mocky.io/v3/aff3f637-d04f-45c0-b002-09be1a143784 is wrong format, you need to remove the last character